# ReactJS render return error Danger: Discarding unexpected node

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a SubMenu component. In its render function it has a simple if-else statement that checks which tab is active. Depending on the active tab, it returns some JSX.

Here is the full SubMenu Component:

```
var SubMenu = React.createClass({
                render: function(){

                    var subCategories = this.props.groupsData.objects[0].sub_groups.map(function(obj, index){
                        return (<li><a href="#">{obj.display_name}</a></li>);   
                    }, this);


                   if (this.props.dprops.active_tab === 0){        // if the active tab is "All Videos"
                        return (<div className="tabbable tabs-left item-list-container col-md-12 items-grid">
                                <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2" ><li className="active"><a href="#">Most Recent</a></li><li><a href="#">Most Popular</a></li><li><SearchBar /></li></ul>
                            <VideoDisplay itemsData={this.props.itemsData}/>
                            </div>);
                    } else {                                       // if the active tab is anything else
                         return (<div className="tabbable tabs-left item-list-container col-md-12 items-grid">
                                <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2" >{subCategories}<li><SearchBar /></li></ul>
                            <VideoDisplay itemsData={this.props.itemsData}/>
                            </div>);
                    }               
                }
            });
```

Everything renders normally at first, but when I switch active Menu tabs, my SubMenu renders incorrectly (see pictures below) and if i change back to Active tab 0,  I receive the error: `Danger: Discarding unexpected node: <li data-reactid=​".0.0.1.0.0.2.0">​…​</li>​`

**The correct display on load:**
[image]
(Most Recent and Most Popular are SubMenu)

**The incorrect display after switching to "Category 1" (Note: the extra Search Box):** [image]

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: It looks like some invalid nested markup. could you show the jsx for SearchBar